# What do these options on dpkg-divert and sed do as it relates to Nvidia package diversion?

Tags: sed, nvidia, dpkg, options

I recently had to use this command as I got some error due to nvidia package diversion, but I don't exactly know how it is working:

```
LC_MESSAGES=C dpkg-divert --list '*nvidia-340*' | sed -nre 's/^diversion of (.*) to .*/\1/p' | xargs -rd'\n' -n1 -- sudo dpkg-divert --remove
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I read about `LC_MESSAGES` and `sed`, and I know how the pipe operator works, but I can't figure out how exactly this command is working with these specific options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LC_MESSAGES=C dpkg-divert --list '*nvidia-340*'
```

lists all the diversions matching the glob pattern `*nvidia-340*`, in English so that the output is of the form “diversion of ... to ... by ...”.

```
sed -nre 's/^diversion of (.*) to .*/\1/p'
```

extracts the text between “diversion of” and “to”, *i.e.* the name of the diverted files. `-nre` is equivalent to `-n -r -e`; `-n` disables automatic pattern space output, so nothing is output unless requested by a `p` command (see the end of the `sed` command); `-r` enables extended regular expressions; and `-e` introduces the script we want to run. In the regular expression, `^diversion of` matches “diversion of ” (including a space) at the start of a line; `(.*)` matches any number of characters, and creates a match group; `to .*` matches “ to ” (including leading and trailing spaces) followed by any character. This is used in a `s` command to replace the complete text with only `\1`, the contents of the match group (*i.e.* the text between “diversion of” and “to”). The final `p` prints the pattern space if the `s` command matched.

```
xargs -rd'\n' -n1 -- sudo dpkg-divert --remove
```

runs `sudo dpkg-divert --remove` on every file output by the previous step, removing the corresponding diversion.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

tries to fix any broken dependencies.

Comment: that really makes is clearer, thanks. can you also explain how the sed command is working, like the -nre flags and "\1/p" at the end. i read about the sed command, 's' is for substitution,  '-n' is used with 'p' to output the substituted values, but how exactly it is extracting the text between “diversion of” and “to”

Comment: See the update, I hope it’s understandable.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.may I know why is it being replaced by '\1' , is it just arbitrary

Comment: `\1` is a place-holder for “the contents of the first match group”. `\2` would be replaced by the contents of the second match group (if there was one), etc.